# Angular 2 conditional ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ngfor

I'm trying to clean up my template code. I have the following:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="condition" *ngFor="let a of array1">
    <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="!condition" *ngFor="let b of array2">
    <p>{{b.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{b.lastname}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to conditionally pick `array1` or `array2` to iterate through using `*ngIf` or something so that I don't have to repeat so much template code? This is just an example; my actual `<li>` contains a lot more content so I really don't want to repeat myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
  <li *ngFor="let a of (condition ? array1 : array2)">
    <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of the `ng-container` which is not recognised by DOM, hence will only be used for a condition. See example below:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let company of companies">
        <ng-container *ngIf="company.tradingRegion == 1">
            <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ company.mseCode }}</td>
         </ng-container>
  </tr>
```

The code above will: `

> Display a list of all companies where the tradingRegion == 1

`

Comment: this will create unnecessary tr rows

Comment: We can swap the the ng-container and the tr tag. No more unnecessary rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template tag with an [ngIf] outside the ngFor loop.

```
<ul>
  <template [ngIf]="condition">
   <li *ngFor="let a of array1">
    <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
   </li>
  </template>
  <template [ngIf]="!condition">
   <li *ngFor="let b of array2">
    <p>{{b.firstname}}</p>
    <p>{{b.lastname}}</p>
   </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Also read about template syntax here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both an `*ngFor` and an `*ngIf` in the same element. You could  create an element inside the `<li>` with the `*ngFor`. Like:

```
<li *ngIf="condition">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let a of array1">
```

Or use the conditional inside the `*ngFor`. Like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let a of (condition?array1:array2)">
```

Or you could use a template like [Peter Salomonsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269407/angular-2-conditional-ngfor/41269599#41269599) instructed.

Answer (score 0):

We can hide the element using bootstrap display property, based on condition.

```
<li [ngClass]="{'d-none': condition}" *ngFor="let a of array1">
 <p>{{a.firstname}}</p>
 <p>{{a.lastname}}</p>
</li>
```